# How to mouse-wheel scroll downwards with tmux

Tags: macos, osx-lion, tmux, iterm2

I've got tmux to scroll up, with the mouse wheel, using `mouse-mode on` in tmux.conf ([here's my entire conf](https://gist.github.com/mahemoff/5176921)).

But I've always had a problem scrolling back down again. Once the cursor hits the bottom of the screen, it immediately scrolls back to the bottom of the whole buffer, where the prompt is. It's not possible to scroll down a few lines in the same way I can scroll up a few lines. In other words, the whole middle section is only visible on the way up.

Comment: I've seen this behaviour too but only when I scroll too fast. I'm using an older MBP with two finger scrolling so maybe my scrolling is slower than your mouse scrolling? Try to go real slow and see if it helps.

Comment: It doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: I added my lines to your gist

Comment: Thanks, just tried it but same as before. I guess the xterm mightn't do much anyway as I'm running this in iterm.

Comment: I'm in iterm too. Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just upgraded from tmux 1.6 to the new tmux 1.8 (compiled from source rather than Homebrew, in case that matters), and it's working again now.

Comment: Upgrading totally fixed this for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What would happen if you turned mousemode off and used the keyboard? Try that.
Have you used burningTyger's settings for your conf?
Try deleting the buffer command, maybe then it won't autoscroll to the prompt line. If you can disable any automatic behavior you might be able to do what you need.
I don't know the OSX terms, but hopefully these concepts might be helpful.

Comment: Don't want to use the keyboard, answered about burningTyger's settings above, and the buffer command is just a key binding.